# Unificando linhas por padrão

Tags: r

Possuo uma base com textos e preciso agrupar todos que estão em um intervalo delimitado pelas letras I e F, exemplo da base:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c(123,123,123,123,456,456,789,789,789,789,789,789,123,123,123,123),
                 tipo = c("I",0,0,"F","I","F",0,"F","I",0,"F","F","I",0,0,"F"),
                 texto = c("AB","cb","ol","ka","po","io","oi","pp","aw","df","xc","pq","aa","ao","ça","xa"))
```

a base final ficaria:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c(123,789,123),
                 resultado = c("cbol", "df", "aoça"))
```

O intervalo entre I e F não é padrão e pode estar sem nenhum texto ou pode ter mais de dez textos, tentei usar um lag mas não consegui

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acabei não pensando em nenhuma resolução elegante, mas consegui chegar no esperado.

#### Código

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(aux = cumsum(if_else(tipo %in% c("I","F"),TRUE,FALSE))) %>% 
  filter(!(lag(tipo) == "F" & lead(tipo) == "F")) %>% 
  filter(!(tipo %in% c("I","F"))) %>% 
  group_by(aux) %>% 
  summarise(
    ID = unique(ID),
    resultado = paste0(texto,collapse = "")
  )
```

#### Resultado

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
    aux    ID resultado
  <int> <dbl> <chr>    
1     1   123 cbol     
2     6   789 df       
3     9   123 aoça
```

Comment: Não precisa usar `if_ele` se a saída desejada for lógica.